# GWT Java MySQL Select Query Column not found however OK in phpMyAdmin

Tags: java, mysql, gwt

When I run the query below in phpMyAdmin it works (I remove the quotes and `+` and substitute `46` for the `?`); however when I run it as part of my GWT Java on the server side I get the error message

`SQLException in getManagementOverview: java.sql.exception: Column ' group2.grp_sub_section' not found`

in the log.

```
String selectQry = ("SELECT group2.grp_sub_section, group2.grp_section, group2.grp_name, group2.grp_district, group2.grp_region, group2.grp_state, " +
              "at_cub_awards.ca_id caid, at_cub_awards.ca_awarded_date awarded, " +
              "at_award.aw_award_type type, at_award.aw_award_name name " +
              "FROM at_group group2, at_group group1, at_account_group, at_cub_details, at_cub_awards, at_award " +
              "WHERE at_account_group.acc_id = ? " +
                "AND at_account_group.grp_id = group1.grp_id " +
                "AND group1.grp_district = group2.grp_district " +
                "AND group2.grp_section = 'Cub' " +
                "AND group2.grp_id = at_cub_details.grp_id " +
                "AND at_cub_details.cd_id = at_cub_awards.cd_id " +
                "AND at_cub_awards.ca_awarded_date IS NOT NULL " +
                "AND at_cub_awards.aw_id = at_award.aw_id " +
                "AND at_award.aw_award_section = 'Cub' " +
              "ORDER BY group2.grp_state, group2.grp_region, group2.grp_district, group2.grp_name, group2.grp_section, group2.grp_sub_section, name;");
```

As requested below I have added my assignment line so the lesson is complete:

```
                while (result.next()) {
                    ManagementOverview managementOverview = new ManagementOverview( 
                            result.getString("group2.grp_state"),
                            result.getString("group2.grp_region"),
                            result.getString("group2.grp_district"),
                            result.getString("group2.grp_name"),
                            result.getString("group2.grp_section"),
                            result.getString(" group2.grp_sub_section"),
                            result.getString("caid"),
                            result.getDate("awarded"),
                            result.getString("type"),
                            result.getString("name"));
                    managementOverviewList.add(managementOverview);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the problem was `result.getString(" group2.grp_sub_section"),` should be `result.getString("group2.grp_sub_section"),` i.e., no space before group2.

Comment: This line was not in your original question. It would be nice, if you could provide that to make your lesson complete :-) Also, I think the correction you posted was wrong. I suspect the additional space was not before `result.getString` but in the string literal `" group2.grp_sub_section"`. Is that correct?

Comment: I have made the necessary changes. I greatly appreciate your input.